# I'm creating an html template that looks like windown but have problems with the resizers

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm creating an windown look like template for web but I have a problem with the resizer, the resizer in the bottom right works perfectly but trying to create the top right resizer don't work and I don't know why I have tried everything but it doesn't work.

Here's the github https://github.com/alhazacod/windowsxphtmltemplate

The JavaScript code:

```
dragru.onmousedown = function(event) {
  let shiftLeft = event.clientX - wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  let shiftTop = event.clientY - wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let shiftBottom = - event.clientY + wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

  function resize(w, h, pageY){
    wwindow.style.top = pageY - shiftTop + 'px';
    if(w>200){
      wwindow.style.width = w + 'px';
    }
    if(h>200){
      console.log(wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - event.pageY);
      wwindow.style.height = (wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - event.pageY) + 'px';

    }
    //wwindow.style.top = pageY - shiftTop + 'px';
  }

  function onMouseMove(event){
    shiftLeft = event.clientX - wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    shiftBottom = -event.clientY + wwindow.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    //if(event.pageY < windowh && event.pageY > 1 && event.pageX < windoww && event.pageX > 1){
      resize(shiftLeft, shiftBottom, event.pageY);
    //}
    /*else{
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      wwindow.onmouseup = null;
    }*/
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

  wwindow.onmouseup = function(){
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    wwindow.onmouseup = null;
  };
};
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue?

Comment: @SuperStormer The top-right corner resizer of the floating windows doesn't work properly

Comment: The window don't resize well when you drag the resizer in the top right. it moves really weird. https://alhazacod.github.io/windowsxphtmltemplate/ try it by your self @SuperStormer